# Client can only connect to server when on the same computer

Tags: java, server, localhost, socketserver

I am trying to create a multiplayer java game and have decided to use a java socket server. The "client" is able to connect and communicate to the server flawlessly when they are both ran on my computer, but when I send the client file to another computer (that is connected to the same network it) is unable to connect to the server, and I can't figure out why. I ran cmd and used to the code netstat -a and was able to confirm that the server is listening on 127.0.0.1:3251 so I believe the problem is with the client.

This is how the server is created:

```
    try {
        this.serverSocket = new ServerSocket();
        this.serverSocket.bind(new InetSocketAddress("localhost",port)); //port is 3251
        window.show("SERVER: " + "Created On Port: " + port);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        window.show("SERVER: " + e.getMessage());
        window.show("SERVER: " + "Unable To Create Server :(");
    }
```

and this is how the client connects:

```
    try {
        socket = new Socket("localhost", 3251);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

When the server accepts a connection it creates a new thread:

```
        Socket socket = this.serverSocket.accept();
        ServerThread serverThread = new ServerThread(socket);
        serverThread.start();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    try {
    socket = new Socket("localhost", 3251);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

"localhost" means your client machine is looking for the server on the same computer. This should be the server ip i.e. 192.168.0.2 or something.

Comment: thank you very much! Changing "localhost" to my ipv4 address fixed everything.

Answer (score 2):

You have two problems:

1. On the server you are creating a `this.serverSocket.bind(new
   InetSocketAddress("localhost",port));`. This creates a server
   socket on the IP address that  `localhost` resolves to. This can be a problem. On most hosts the
   `localhost` will resolve to `127.0.0.1` a loopback address and your
   server socket will only listen on that. To be able to listen to all
   NICs on that machine use `new InetSocketAddress(port)` [see the java doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/InetSocketAddress.html#InetSocketAddress(int)) for this construcotr. Or discover and use the specific host name of the server.
2. Like @Nick Eu pointed out on the client you are trying to connect to the server on `localhost`. You need to have a way for your client to be configured so that it knows where the server is and use that.

To Clarify this further:
A [socket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_socket) is a IP:Port that is used for communication. Say a host has two NIC's with IP's 192.168.2.1 and 10.0.0.2. Now if you bind  server socket (say 8000) to the `192.168.2.1` IP. This port will be only accessible by using this combination `192.168.2.1:8000`, similarly if you bind it to the `10.0.0.2` IP it will be accessible only through that IP. And if you bind localhost (aka [Loopback address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost)) it will be only accessible for clients on that host. This is useful if you want to run a server that is restricted to only clients on that host.